# Get Value in Array by index in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, arraylist, indexing

I have two arrays and I want to get Value in Array1 by Index from array2 so I want code to get value in array by specific index

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you show the work you have done so far, that is provide your current even if non-working source code.

Comment: You know how to access an item in an array via index? If so, what is the question about?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you can acces value from array like this

```
var value = Array1[0];
```

If you want to get value by index from Array2 you need to do it like this, but i don't know why you should to this, it can cause easily exception by everflow.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array2.lenght; i++)
{
    var value = Array1[i];
}
```